# Why the digital signature is invalid?

Tags: pdf, certificate, digital-signature

I have signed a pdf digitally with a valid certificate installed as a personal certificate in the keystore.
When I open the file in my computer the signature is valid and the signer is the current user.
However, when I used to send it or open the file in another computer, the signature validity is unknown, also the signer's identity is unknown too. like shown in this image :

[image]

I would like to know how to make that certificate valid whatever the computer?

Comment: Sounds like the certificate is self-signed, more information is require

Comment: When I've installed the certificate I've chosen to export it as a personal, not trusted certification authority. This certificate is delivered from a CA

Comment: This CA is trusted on both machines?  The message being displayed indicates it is not.

Comment: No, the CA is declared in the first machine,  where the document was signed for the first time. How to make other machines recognize it without installing it ?

Comment: If the CA isn't trusted on each machine, then you as a human ignore this message, or through software add the trust.  You have to tell the machine you trust the CA and the certificate it created otherwise there is no circle of trust.

Comment: Okey thank you, Please how to mention to a software or a tool that the certificate is trustful, in a way that will be recognized in every machine?

Comment: I already have.  You indicated you didn't want to install the CA on this second machine, so your only left with, as a human verifying and trusting the the certificate yourself for each certificate that generated a signature.

Comment: If I understand well, I have to validate the certificate using a pdf reader? that's all?